# Opening and extracting data from Shapefiles?

Tags: shapefile, import

We are in need of US highway data.

We found it for Florida at the state GIS [website](http://www.dot.state.fl.us/planning/statistics/gis/roaddata.shtm).

We downloaded the data for Florida highway intersections from [here](ftp://ftp.dot.state.fl.us/fdot/co/planning/transtat/gis/shapefiles/intersection.zip) (this is a zip file).

How do we use these files and extract the geocode values of the intersections (exits) from them?

Comment: Which software do you have available?

Comment: Any of the top hits found by Googling "shapefile" provide detailed descriptions of shapefiles and software (or links to software) and applets for reading them.

Comment: The top hit for Googling about shapefiles pulled up this question for me!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can download and use QGIS which is a simple and effective free G.I.S. software. http://www.qgis.org

Answer (score 3):

Among many other options, you could open the files with the free software package [saga gis](http://www.saga-gis.org)

If you use modules\shapes\add coordinates to points you will get a table with all the xy locations and their attributes.

Answer (score 2):

in arcmap 10

1) do a query on the features you would like to select and export them to a new layer
(using selection - on the top; select by attributes)

2) enable the arctoolbox (by going to the geoprocessing menu on the top)

3) open the geocoding tools

4) use the geocode addresses to create the export file you need - if that is not what you want; try to take a look at the data management toolbox and see if you can find one that suits your needs.

Comment: If mohang isn't familiar with the shapefile format, I doubt that he has GIS software that costs several thousand dollars...

Comment: although he has managed to get almost 100 reputation on a GIS Q&A site..!

Answer (score -1):

Go to http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisexplorer/help/index.html#/About_importing_content_to_ArcGIS_Online/01560000004s000000/   and download the version you need. Works real well.