# What is the process of converting geodata in ArcMap 10 to WKT format?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, convert, well-known-text, data

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shapefiles to Text](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/shapefiles-to-text)

What is the process of converting geodata in ArcMap 10 to WKT format?
I am not a programmer so much, but will learn if needed. I have a set of shapefiles and need to convert them to WKT format. Please advise on the process required to do this.

Comment: Do you need the attributes as well, or just the WKT of individual geometries?

Comment: @artwork Thanks for pointing that out.  Although that question doesn't specify ArcGIS, an ArcGIS (=ArcMap) solution is offered in the answer at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7339/shapefiles-to-text/7344#7344.