# How can I convert WKT to SHP?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, shapefile, fme-form, well-known-text, advanced-license-level

Using ArcGIS, ArcInfo and fme, I would like to transform data which contains wkt geometries (points, lines and polygons) into SHP. Has anyone a workflow for doing such a transformation?

Comment: ..sounds like [a job for ogr2ogr](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24947/how-can-i-convert-a-csv-file-of-wkt-data-to-a-shape-file-using-ogr2ogr).

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to program python: arcpy has the "fromWKT" function, which can read a WKT string and return a geometry object. See http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018v0000008s000000 .

FME has a WKT reader also: http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_ReadersWriters/Default.htm#wkt/wkt.htm