# JSON to shapefile

Tags: javascript, convert, esri-geodatabase, json

I have a .json with multiple geometry types within it.

It's actually 'open' data:
[link to data](https://open.alberta.ca/opendata/inventory-of-major-alberta-projects#summary)

Any tips on converting to a shapefile or similar?
Do I have to break the JSON file into different files, one per geometry type?

I'm open to Python or similar.

http://ogre.adc4gis.com/  fails - not sure why.

The ESRI tool: **JSON To Features** won't work, probably because it has multiple geometry types.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/geojson-to-esri-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr) which points to OGR2OGR, that's if it's GEOJSON.

Alternatively you could try python'ing it into [WKT then using OGR2OGR](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/211822/converting-wkt-to-shp).