# Ungenerate command in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcmap, geoprocessing

I am searching for the ungenerate command in argis10 desktop. I get to know that is available only for workstation. But i don't have workstation. Is there any way to use this command or any other way to get the same result as that of ungenerate command.

Comment: The particular answer that I recommend you look at on the earlier duplicate is http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7344/115  and I also recommend that you add your vote to the ArcGIS Idea to [Generate and Ungenerate all vector feature classes from/to ASCII](http://ideas.arcgis.com/ideaView?id=08730000000boEsAAI).

Comment: Converting to ascii is closely akin to ungenerate, but not a duplicate. Ascii is general, many/any text format can fit, while ungenerate is specific. Please reopen (I have a direct answer ;-)

Comment: ettols has an ungenerate command. I agree with polygeo the shape to ascii is the same as ungenerate.  http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoWizards/gw_main.htm

Comment: Guess I've been outvoted. ;-) Here's the short form of my answer: I fixed a couple of bugs and updated the 9.x developer sample of WriteFeaturesFromTextFile for 10.x, grab it from https://github.com/maphew/arcplus/blob/master/ArcToolbox/Scripts/ungenerate.py