# Converting Feature coordinates to text (same as output from UNGENERATE command in ArcInfo Workstation)?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, python-2.7, arcinfo-workstation

I am trying to convert stream segments to text. This is function for the script

```
#function to convert feature to text as ungenerate command in ArcGIS workstation

def featureTotext(path,feature,TextFileName):

import string, os, sys, locale, arcgisscripting
gp = arcgisscripting.create()
gp.overwriteoutput = 1
msgNotEnoughParams = "Incorrect number of input parameters."
msgUseValidDecimalPointSep = "Please use one of the valid decimal point separators."
try:
    os.chdir(path)
    inputFC = feature
    outFile = open(TextFileName, "w")
    sepchar=""
    inDesc = gp.describe(inputFC)
    inRows = gp.searchcursor(inputFC)
    inRow = inRows.next()
   # outFile.write(inDesc.ShapeType + "\n")

    while inRow:
        feat = inRow.GetValue(inDesc.ShapeFieldName)

        partnum = 0
        partcount = feat.partcount

        while partnum < partcount:
            outFile.write("\t"+str(inRow.GetValue('GRID_CODE')) + "\n")
            print inRow.GetValue('GRID_CODE')
            part = feat.getpart(partnum)
            part.reset()
            pnt = part.next()
            pnt_count = 0
            while pnt:
                outLine = "\t" + str(pnt.x) + "\t" + str(pnt.y) + "\n"
                if sepchar == "": outFile.write(outLine)
                else: outFile.write(outLine.replace(".", sepchar))
                pnt = part.next()
                pnt_count += 1
                if not pnt:
                    pnt = part.next()
                    if pnt:
                        outFile.write("InteriorRing\n")

            partnum += 1
            outFile.write("END\n")
        inRow = inRows.next()
    outFile.write("END")
    outFile.flush()
    outFile.close()
    print outFile

except Exception, ErrorDesc:
    gp.AddError(ErrorDesc[0])
    if outFile: outFile.close()
    gp.AddError(gp.getmessages(2))
```

This script gives output similar as the "ungenerate" command in ArcGIS workstation. When used, this function gives the fewer output points than using the ungenerate command.

Output from this function look like :

    1354 
    391367.254831      9456327.37568 
    389617.254831      9458077.37568 
    389617.254831      9459077.37568 
    388117.254831      9460577.37568 
    387117.254831      9460577.37568 
    380117.254831      9467577.37568 

 END

I want to have more points (smaller interval) while extracting X and Y coordinates from a feature. How can I do this ?

Comment: If you are trying to create the same output as Arc: UNGENERATE, then did you try the suggestion at http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/7344/115 ?

Comment: Yes I already tried with that.  I want to know about extracting X Y coordinates at finer scale

Comment: Asking for coordinates at "finer scale" doesn't make much sense -- UNGENERATE did not do on-the-fly densification.  And your logic for handling multiple parts is flawed (not that stream segments are likely to be multi-part).

Comment: is the version tag correct? arc 10.1 - using arcgisscripting?

Answer (score 1):

The script will return an array of point objects for each part (returned by the GetPart method) for each record in the feature class. The number of points returned is not defined by any tolerance; the array will contain all the vertices that make up that polygon part.

The only way to get more points would be to place them on the existing lines, which (if I'm understanding the your requirement correctly) would be redundant.

"http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001t000000"

"http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/IGpDescribeGeometry_Interface/002n000001nw000000/"

Answer (score 1):

> I want to have more points (smaller interval) while extracting X and Y coordinates from a feature. How can I do this ?

If you have access to Standard or Advanced license levels, run [Densify](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001v00000003000000) (`arcpy.Densify_edit`) on the lines before converting to text. Be aware that this can change the shape of the geometry especially along curves, though individual vertices should remain on the original line's path.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how this will be done by script, but if you have a vector data and want it in a text file or in excel format then:

1. Add layer in ArcMap
2. Open attribute table
3. Select all the features and from right click you select copy features and paste them in excel or word file.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but I don't want the output in excel or word file format. I want to generate the same output as ungenerate command in ArcGIS Workstation

Comment: @Singh If you are interested in the outcome of this Q&A then you should Favorite it by clicking the icon beneath the up/down vote counter next to the question.